# Xamarin Tools - Visual Studio 2017 does not see my Pixel 3 XL

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently running on VS 2017 Version 15.8.9 (or whatever the most recent build is).  I have a a pixel 3 XL.  My pixel is in developer mode.  My windows 10 system can see that the pixel is connected to my laptop, my pixel is showing up as a device on my Windows 10 system.  the device manager in windows sees the pixel 3 xl.  I attempted to install the google usb device driver for android, however windows reports that the most appropriate device driver is already installed. 
 Unfortunately, my xamarin forms project does not see the pixel as a device to run against.  when I run "adb devices", the android sdk does not see the device.

Any thoughts on what to do to have the pixel3xl to be seen?  Does Xamarin have good support yet for Android 9?

TIA,
Wally

Comment: I have solved the problem.  I had forgotten to turn on USB debugging on the device.  Now that I have enabled USB debugging, the problem seems to be solved.